# How to make an AJAX spreadsheet or an editable and navigatable web table/grid?

Tags: ajax, spreadsheet

[Many web applications today](http://ajax.phpmagazine.net/2007/03/ajax_spreadsheets_roundup.html) have spreadsheets. I was trying to make a very similar table, but with reduced funcionality:

1. editable cells
2. pressing the arrow keys,  or  would make you go to a cell next to the current one (in the proper direction)

I found [ext grid](http://extjs.com/deploy/ext/docs/output/Ext.grid.Grid.html) and [YUI DataTable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/), and besides they being editable I haven't found an easy way to make them keyboard navigatable.

Anyone knows how to configure them properly? Anyone knows another JS library that would help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://os.arandomurl.com/jqueryspreadsheet/ 
arrows work

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/sheet

Comment: The second one also accepts arrows
http://jqueryplugins.weebly.com/uploads/3/1/3/8/313814/jquery.sheet.html

Answer (score 1):

Use either of those grids, and just watch the keyboard keyup event. Check if it's an arrow, and if so, move the focus. Both those grids support selecting the cell via code, so you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Gelsheet](http://gelsheet.sourceforge.net) 
A Google Doc like application (reduced), but opensource ! 
You can install and customize as you want. Also there are plugins for wordpress, opengoo and fengoffice.

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin for jQuery called [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). Sounds pretty nice.